# Hexagon hover to Square with CSS

Tags: css, hover, shapes, css-shapes

I recently saw [this codepen][1] in which an octagon (wrongly called hexagon) is transformed into a square when hovered on.

I want to do that, but with a 300px sized hexagon turning into a square.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/EdwinToh/pen/ktaxH?editors=110
```

Comment: @jbutler483 You've misread the question (as in fact did I)...he doesn't want an octagon...he wants a **hexagon**...even though he hasn't provided the code for one.

Comment: You can have a look at this : [elastic hexagon](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/EaMmmz) when you click it, it becomes a square. It uses svg to change the shape froma hexagon to a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with this css:

```
#hexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    margin:50px;
}
#hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid red;
}
#hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid red;
}
#hexagon:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top:-25px;
}
#hexagon:hover:after {display:none;}
#hexagon:hover:before {display:none;}
```

you may have what you want: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/u2Lcxy7z/4/)**

or a bit animated: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/u2Lcxy7z/5/)**

**Edited:** Updated both fiddles so the width is 300px as asked for the op

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro! I have a new question, that perhaps you can answer. With the second hexagon, the animated one, what would happen if I have text on top of it? When it rotates the text will also rotate. Is there a way of keeping the text straight?

Comment: Well, yes, the text will rotate if you place it inside the hexagon but a better solution woudl be to position the text inside same container as the hexagon with position absolute and then it won't rotate. Here you have a fiddle with some changes and text (and a change of hover to avoid some flickering when you hovered over the pseudoelements): http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/u2Lcxy7z/8/

Answer (score 2):

To create a Hexagon, you could create it with two pseudo elements width borders.

You could then animate it to your liking (I have included a rotation for stylistic purposes only).

```css
.hex:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 75px solid tomato;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  top: -75px;
}
.hex {
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.hex:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -75px;
  border-top: 75px solid tomato;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.hex:hover:before {
  top: 0;
}
.hex:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.hex:hover {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  transform-origin:center center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex">
  <div>
```

---

A more calculated result/approach would be to use:

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 173.21px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
  transition:all 0.6s;
}
.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  transition:all 0.6s;
}
.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 86.60px solid tomato;
}
.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 86.60px solid tomato;
}
.hexagon:hover:before,
.hexagon:hover:after {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.hexagon:hover{
  margin:0;
  height:300px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

---

## Image-supported approach.

You could use the likes of borders on the pseudo elements to 'cover up' the corners. below is an approach which allows a background image as well:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 150px solid white;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 150px solid white;
  top: -50px;
  height: 100px;
  right: -50px;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 150px solid white;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 150px solid white;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
div:hover:before,
div:hover:after {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: SO basically you have wrotten same answer than I did?

Comment: Alvaro: no. For one, my snippets are of the correct proportions, as well as including an idea of how it is generated. I was also currently editing to include a background image approach, although my internet died and so am reduced to writing this on a phone, if you must know.

Comment: Well. Fine by me. I guess all people shares different points of views and a single sentence of 10 words explain more than a fiddle. Silly me I am use to delete my answers out of respect, when I have been writting at the same time (case NOT to be applied here) and, after posting it , I found someone has post the answer sooner. Guess a bit of semantic makes answers totally different. Ty for the insight and I hope you have a great day. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the height and width of the bubble class to 300px

```
 .bubble {

  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;

  background:#000;

  -webkit-transition: .2s all ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .2s all ease-out;
  transition: .2s all ease-out;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);

  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: You've misread the question (as in fact did I)...he doesn't want an octagon...he wants a hexagon...even though he hasn't provided the code for one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `clip-path` to achieve this. Note that, unfortunately, this propery is current only supported by Webkit & Blink browsers, using the `-webkit-` prefix ([See caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)).

[More information on `clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

**EXAMPLE**

```css
#hexagon{
    background:#000;
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 25%,100% 75%,50% 100%,0 75%,0 25%);
    clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 25%,100% 75%,50% 100%,0 75%,0 25%);
    height:300px;
    margin:20px auto;
    transition:all .5s;
    width:300px;
}
#hexagon:hover{
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 0,100% 100%,50% 100%,0 100%,0 0);
    clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 0,100% 100%,50% 100%,0 100%,0 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon"></div>
```